# How do I search for multiple rows in a table or search from concatenated values?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL and here is a DB table called "profile".
[image: table profile]

Then my project requires me to perform some kind of "advanced search" as below on the profiles. I can choose 'match any' or 'match all', then the field (Full Name, Email, etc), condition (is, is not, contains, does not contain, etc) and type the values.
[image: The advanced search interface]

Firstly, I tried to concatenate the fields and here is the table.

[image: concatenated fields]

Then to achieve the advanced search, I used the where clause followed by like, and/or as follows.

```
SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(`field_name`,'=',`field_value`)) AS `profile_values`, 
FROM `test`.`profiles`
where `profile_values` like 'Full Name=%Bryan%' or `profile_values` like 'Phone=%123456789%' 
group by `user_id`
```

This query will give 2 results (user_id = 1 and 3). If I need to match all the searching fields, I simply needed to change the 'or' to 'and' in the query.

However, 3 results (user_id=1,2,3) instead of 2 (user_id=2,3) will be shown if I changed the query like below:
..... where `profile_values` like 'Full Name=%B%'

It seems that the query will search for 'b' in any part of the profile_values.

Any advice on how to modify the search query? Or should I not concatenate the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query

```
FullName=%B%
```

will look for anything after FullName that includes a B, you are correct in that.
You need to structure your query better.

You don't need to create that second table with the concatenated field.
Instead write a query that passes the parameters into a query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE
FullName LIKE '%B%'
AND Email LIKE '%xyz%'
```

The code structure for creating the query will be more complex and you'll need to include AND and OR but it'll solve your LIKE problem and remove the need for the second table.